# Meaning of “ci” with “servire”

Tags: meaning, particles

"La nostra casa è piccola ma c’è tutto quello che **ci** serve."

What would be the meaning of "ci" in the sentence above? Is it a "verbo pronominale"? In the dictionary I found the meaning to be "essere cliente", e.g. "per il formaggio ci serviamo da Bianchi", but this meaning does not seem to fit here.

Comment: I've modified the question's title to avoid having two questions with the same title.

Comment: In this case “ci” is a pronoun with the meaning of “a noi”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's simply the object form (indirect in this case) of "noi", just like you'd have "la mia casa è piccola ma c'è tutto quello che mi serve" in the singular.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the entry in the dictionary.